# Subtracting characters in a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I need the output of the program to be ten "*" symbols and then each following line is one less star until there is only one. I need to do this using a loop.
I am able to add stars but not subtract them. Please take a look at my program and see if you can help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int count;
    String stars;
    stars = "**********";
    String star = "*";
    System.out.println(stars);

    for (count = 10;  0 < count;)
    {
        stars = (stars - star);
        System.out.println(stars);
        count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: try the substring method

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. When you are creating question you can see preview of how it will look like with your current formatting, so before you decide to post it take your time and format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `String - String`. You may use `String.substring`

```
 stars = stars .substring(0, stars .length() - 1);
 System.out.println(stars);
```

**Note** that the correct way to write `for` loop is:

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

So you should write your `for` loop as:

```
for (count = 10;  0 < count; count--)
{
    stars = stars .substring(0, stars .length() - 1);
    System.out.println(stars);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
stars = (stars.replaceFirst("\\*", ""));
```

instead of

```
stars = (stars - star);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =10;i>0;i--){

    for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
        System.out.print('*');
    System.out.print('\n');//exit main loop

 }
```

Comment: Couple of quick pointers we would typically use final char '*' single quotes because its a literal, Also keep in mind how many variables you used and how many i used solving these small problems with little to no use of memory will come in handy if your interested in larger programs that require serious concern of memory usage. I also noticed your usage of decrement at the end, you may notice i put mine with the loop parameter body to stay organized

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to print the asterisks in a loop for each line, without maintaining a string throughtout the process:

```
for (count = 10;  0 < count; --count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you're adamant about preserving the string throughout the program's execution, I'd suggest not using a `String`, but a mutable `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder stars = new StringBuilder("**********");
while (stars.length() > 0) {
    System.out.println(stars);
    stars.setLength(stars.length() - 1);
}
```